# Python | Regex | get numbers from the text

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have text of the form

```
Refer to Annex 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0 containing information etc,

or

Refer to Annex 1.0.1, 1.1.1 containing information etc,
```

I need to extract the numbers that the `Annex` is referring to.
I have tried lookbehind regex as below.

```
m = re.search("(?<=Annex)\s*[\d+.\d+,]+", text)

print(m)
>>> <re.Match object; span=(11, 15), match=' 1.1'>
```

I get output as just 1.1, but I don't get remaining. How do I get all the numbers followed by keyword `Annex` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following two-step solution:

```py
import re
texts = ['Refer to Annex 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0 containing information etc,', 'Refer to Annex 1.0.1, 1.1.1 containing information etc,']
rx = re.compile(r'Annex\s*(\d+(?:(?:\W|and)+\d)*)')
for text in texts:
    match = rx.search(text)
    if match:
        print(re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)*', match.group(1)) )
```

See the [Python](https://ideone.com/xsAZCQ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EWaCT0/1), the output is

```
['1.1', '1.2', '2.0']
['1.0.1', '1.1.1']
```

The `Annex\s*(\d+(?:(?:\W|and)+\d)*)` regex matches

- `Annex` - the string `Annex`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:(?:\W|and)+\d)*)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then zero or more occurrences of a non-word char or `and` string and then a digit.

Then, when the match is found, all dot-separated digit sequences are extracted with `\d+(?:\.\d+)*`.